# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting the

> ErrorException: *Trying to get property of non-object*

I'm trying to display all the relationship that is link using this function. The relationship is ->

-Card can have many notes, Notes only have one card.
-Each notes contain only one user, User contain only one card. My code is:

## Model

1. Note

   ```
   class Note extends Model
   {
   protected $fillable = ['body'];

       public function cards()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
       }

       public function users()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id');
       }

   }
   ```
2. User

   ```
   class User extends Authenticatable
   {
       use Notifiable;

       public function note()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Note::class);
       }

       protected $fillable = [
           'name', 'email', 'password',
       ];

       protected $hidden = [
           'password', 'remember_token',
       ];
   }
   ```
3. Card

   ```
   class Card extends Model
   {
        public function notes()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Note::class);//relationship
       }

       public function addNote(Note $note)
       {
           return $this->notes()->save($note);
       }
   }
   ```

## Controller

1. CardsController

   ```
   class cardsController extends Controller
   {
       public function index()
       {
           $cards = Card::all();
           return view('cards.index',compact('cards'));
       }

   public function show(Card $card)
   {
       $card->load('notes.user'); **The Error is here.**
       $return $card;
       return view('cards.show',compact('card'));
   }
   ```

   }
2. NotesController

   ```
   class notesController extends Controller
   {

       public function store(Request $request, Card $card)
       {
           $card->addNote(
                   new Note($request->all())
               ); 

           return back();
      }

       public function edit(Note $note)
       {
           return view('notes.edit',compact('note'));
       }

       public function update(Request $request, Note $note)
       {
           $note -> update($request -> all());

           return back();
       }
   }
   ```

## DB

1.
[notes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntk8S.jpg)

**$card->load('notes.user');**
-when I just put (notes) in the `cardControllers` function, it will appear all data that link from card and notes table.
-but when I try to add (notes.user) it said that trying to get non property object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try 'notes.users'  .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You should also use https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty to check first if fetched collection is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common and self explanatory error, it comes when you are trying to access a class property which doesn't really exist.

To avoid this, use **isset()** before access the property.

Comment: The data is already there, but the tables cant connect between each other

Answer (score 0):

try like this in notes controller
**`$notes=DB::table('notes')->get();
return view('cards.show')->with('notes',$notes);`**
it will work.

In view if u want display use 
**`@foreach($notes as $row)
{{$row->user_id}}
@endforeach`**

`

Comment: yup correct, but it  only connect note table and card table only not the user table.

Comment: left join you can use to connect with the user table based on your data

Answer (score 0):

```
$card->load('notes.user');
```

This means you are trying to load two relations from `Card` model - notes and user. Looking at your model `user` relation is missing from your `Card` model. Also, in your note model you've mentioned it as `users'. It would be better if you use singular term across the app.

Since no relation has been loaded, it's obvious to get `property of non-object` while accessing `$model->relation` or `$model->relation->property`.